An attempt has been made to use a data extension 'MySQL' error in Visual Studios 2019
I am using VS2019 to open a reporting project that uses MySQL. When I click on Preview of any of the reports, I get this error:

I have been searching everywhere for a good solution, but none have been working out for me.

Doesn't this address the process?  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2615/creating-a-ssrs-report-using-a-mysql-data-source/

@TimRoberts Well I am using Visual Studios 2019 and the Reports Project is already made, so I unsure on how this will help

Well, you have to set up the MySQL ODBC connector on your system before you can edit a project that uses it.  That's what the web page describes.

@TimRoberts So I set up a connector with steps 1 through 7. I do not know what the other steps mean if the reporting project is already made. But I can still getting the exact error.

There's just some disconnect between your report project and your ODBC connection.  You'll have to dig in to the settings for the reporting project to see where that is configured.
